How to factor $k^2(k+1)^2 -c(k+1)^2 +k^2c +c^2 +c$
Basically I need to prove that  $k^2(k+1)^2 -c(k+1)^2 +k^2c +c^2 +c = [k(k+1) -c]^2$.
When I first saw polynomial I thought that it could’t be factored into anything meaningful, let alone a square of integer number but I saw in the solution page of the book that it does factor and it also gives true in wolfram alpha, being equal.
The real problem goes like this given that $a,b,c$ are integers and that $a+c$ and $b+c$ are squares of consecutive integer numbers,prove that $ab +c$ and $ab +a +b +c$ are also squares of consecutive integer numbers.
I managed to solve this problem the long and hard way.However in solution it goes simple: $a+c=k^2$, $b+c=(k+1)^2$,
$a=k^2 -c$, $b=(k+1)^2 -c$.
$a*b +c= [k(k+1) -c]^2$
I couldn’t transform left part of that equation into right.
It also confuses me how to group polynomial with 5(odd)number of members.

There is a typo. We have to deal with the (corrected) expression
$$k^2(k+1)^2-c(k+1)^2\color{red}-k^2c+c^2+c$$
Expanding the first term doesn't help much, but expanding the second term does give a cancellation:
$$k^2(k+1)^2-\color{blue}{c(k+1)^2}-k^2c+c^2+c$$
simplifies to
$$k^2(k+1)^2-(\color{blue}{k^2c+2kc+c})-k^2c+c^2+c$$
and then
$$k^2(k+1)^2-2k^2c-2kc+c^2$$
At this point, it should be rather clear since
$$2k^2c+2kc=2k(k+1)c$$
Hope this helps. :)
